# React native function run olny if i run it twice

Tags: javascript, react-native

I#m making this React Native Calendar app where user can save tasks on specific dates. Using the react-natuive-calendar api from this git: https://github.com/wix/react-native-calendars
The user get to log in the app, and the task are saved as object list. The problem I'm facing is that when i press on task an alert is shown, if the user press 'Yes' the task should be removed from the list, and after 2 sec the list should be refreshed. But in order for this to work i have to do it twice. Long story short, why do i have to run the same function twice in order for this to work?

```
 //function that takes in the date of task and REMOVE it
  const RemoveTask = (taskDate) => {
    GloballyConst.tasks[taskDate] = [];
    SetNewItems();
    
    //list of task refreshing after 3 sec
    const interval =setInterval(() => {
      setRefreshing(true);  
    }, 3000)  
  }

  //on Task clicked alert pop up to confirm removing
  const createTwoButtonAlert = () =>
  Alert.alert('Remove Task', 'Are you sure you want to delete'+ {clickedDate}, [{
    text: 'Cancel',
    onPress: () => console.log('Cancel Pressed'),
    style: 'cancel',
    },
    {text: 'Yes', onPress: () => {
      //Function to remove task
      RemoveTask(clickedDate);
    }},
  ]);

  
  //this is the way task will look like
  const renderItem = (item) => {
    return (
      <TouchableOpacity 
      onPress={() => {
        //set cliked date is set to the date of the object
        setClickedDate(item.date)
        //colling the function that show allert
        createTwoButtonAlert()
      }} 
      style={styles.taskCont}>
        <View style={{flexDirection:'row', justifyContent:'space-between'}}>
          <Text style={{color:'#FFFFFF'}}>{item.name}</Text>
          <Image style={styles.icon} source={require('../assets/iconsHome/important.png')}/>
        </View>
        <View style={{flexDirection:'row', alignItems: 'center'}}>
          <Image style={styles.iconSmall}  source={require('../assets/iconsHome/clock.png')}/>
          <Text style={{color:'rgba(255,255,255,0.5)', padding:5}}>{item.timeStart}</Text>
        </View>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    );
  }
```

The list looks like this:

```
module.exports = {
    //this is the list of task and get items from addTaskScreen
    tasks: {
        '2023-02-20': [{name: 'Make Youtube Video', timeStart: '12:00', date: '2023-02-20'}],
    }
};
```

After runing the function once and console out the tasks, the task that should be removed is still there, and if i run in again it's gone.

Comment: Please post the "command" that you are "running". The state of your component is not changing ...

Comment: which one do you mean?

Comment: Do you have an onClick event or other event you can provide? Meaning the trigger event ...

Comment: You were right, the problem was the way i was calling the functions. Thanks!

Comment: I'm glad that I could help you out with that. That little piece of advice cost me three days two years ago ;)

Comment: Thats why we love code, right? :))

Answer (score 0):

!SOLVED!

The problem was the way the Alert function is called.

before:

```
const renderItem = (item) => {
    return (
      <TouchableOpacity 
      onPress={() => {
        //set cliked date is set to the date of the object
        setClickedDate(item.date)
        //colling the function that show allert
        createTwoButtonAlert()
      }} 
      style={styles.taskCont}>
        <View style={{flexDirection:'row', justifyContent:'space-between'}}>
          <Text style={{color:'#FFFFFF'}}>{item.name}</Text>
          <Image style={styles.icon} source={require('../assets/iconsHome/important.png')}/>
        </View>
        <View style={{flexDirection:'row', alignItems: 'center'}}>
          <Image style={styles.iconSmall}  source={require('../assets/iconsHome/clock.png')}/>
          <Text style={{color:'rgba(255,255,255,0.5)', padding:5}}>{item.timeStart}</Text>
        </View>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    );
```

after:

```
const renderItem = (item) => {
    return (
      <TouchableOpacity 
      onPress={() => {
        //set cliked date is set to the date of the object
        setClickedDate(item.date)
        //colling the function that show allert
        createTwoButtonAlert(item.date)
      }} 
      style={styles.taskCont}>
        <View style={{flexDirection:'row', justifyContent:'space-between'}}>
          <Text style={{color:'#FFFFFF'}}>{item.name}</Text>
          <Image style={styles.icon} source={require('../assets/iconsHome/important.png')}/>
        </View>
        <View style={{flexDirection:'row', alignItems: 'center'}}>
          <Image style={styles.iconSmall}  source={require('../assets/iconsHome/clock.png')}/>
          <Text style={{color:'rgba(255,255,255,0.5)', padding:5}}>{item.timeStart}</Text>
        </View>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    );
```